# Downloading instagram images from URL lists

Tags: python, instagram, imagedownload

Currently I have a list of instagram post and I am trying to download images (only pics not videos) to analyze these pictures.
So far I use instaloader but somehow I have an error in the middle.
Is there any other way to download images from the posts?
example url is this : [https://www.instagram.com/p/CpN_0RqMM94/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
Thank you in advance!

```
d = pd.read_csv("alldata.csv") #list of insta URLs
os.chdir("..")

for f in range(len(d)):
        links = d["Link"]
        print (links[f])
        L = instaloader.Instaloader()
        post_url = links[f]
        post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(L.context, post_url.split('p/')[1].strip('/ '))            
        L.download_post(post,"filename")
                                                
        time.sleep(5)
        f2+=1
```